# Operators for non-primitive boxed types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, boxing

I have the following class definition:

```
template <typename T>
class MyBox {
public:
    MyBox(T value) { _value = value; }
    operator T() const { return _value;  }
private:
    T _value;
};

typedef MyBox<int> MyInt;
typedef MyBox<std::string> MyString;
```

When I try to use operators on my typedefs like this

```
bool first = MyInt(1) == MyInt(1);    // works
bool second = std::string(MyString("a")) == std::string(MyString("a"));    //works
bool third = MyString("a") == MyString("a");   // does not compile
```

the compiler complains about the third comparison

> no operator "==" matches these operands. operand types are: MyString == MyString

and this happens with any other non-primitve boxing (e.g. `MyBox<float>` works but `MyBox<std::map<int,int> >` not. Why is that so?

This is especially unclear to me because for the first and second comparison the `operator T()` is used - why can't that be done automatically for `MyString` as well?

**UPDATE:** Is there a simple solution to this other than providing the specific operators for each non-primitive template? And what to do with `MyString("a") == std::string("a")`?

Comment: @LogicStuff, wonderful stuff! Thanks for finding it.

Comment: I am not really sure about closure, though. The duplicate explains 'why', but not 'how to fix'.

Comment: @SergeyA How to fix is pretty obvious (there's no `operator==` so you have to write one). The why is the much more interesting/difficult question.

Comment: @Barry, i do agree with 'why' being more interesting question (for instance, I did not why). But, OP has directly asked for help: `UPDATE: Is there a simple solution to this other than providing the specific operators for each non-primitive template? And what to do with MyString("a") == std::string("a")`. I have tried to address this question.

Comment: @LogicStuff thanks for finding the other question. From the linked "original"'s answer: ``template argument deduction doesn't look through implicit conversions``. Does my question not show a counter-argument to that, since the MyInt() comparision steps in the implicit conversion? So maybe the difference between primitive and non-primitive types is what makes this question unique, do you share that opinion?

Comment: @PhilLab The builtin `operator==` for primitive types has different mechanics than a function template, it's not defined as one, while `std::string`'s `operator==` is.

Comment: All the comments and answers mention a possible dup, but that link is now gone. Can someone who knows what it was add a link in a comment to it?

Comment: @RobK it was http://stackoverflow.com/q/35544648/1531708 and for me it still appears on the left below "Linked"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasons on why it works for built-in types, but does't work for custom types is answered in the following SO quesiton: [using user-defined conversions with implicit conversions in comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544648/using-user-defined-conversions-with-implicit-conversions-in-comparisons). In short, this is because type conversion does not happen for template-deduced types. And while built-in `operator==` for `int` is not a template (and thus can be found using type conversion when `MyBox<int>` is used), `operator==` for `std::string` is a template.

However, the question mentioned above doesn't have details on how to solve this problem. Here is how: add following free functions

```
template<class T>
bool operator==(const MyBox<T>& lhs, const MyBox<T>& rhs) {
    return static_cast<const T&>(lhs) == static_cast<const T&>(rhs);
}

template<class T>
bool operator==(const MyBox<T>& lhs, const T& rhs) {
    return static_cast<const T&>(lhs) == rhs;
}

template<class T>
bool operator==(const T& lhs, const MyBox<T>& rhs) {
    return lhs == static_cast<const T&>(rhs);
}
```

Comment: You are right, the "how to solve that?" is probably more important, thanks for that :-). But: this has to be done for every operator (``<,>, <=, >=, ==, !=, ....``) I want to use, right? Do I really have to write ``#Operators * 3`` free functions, looking all quite similar?

Comment: @PhilLab, the question 'why' is answered in the duplicate. I answer the question 'how to fix this problem', which doesn't seem to be addressed in the duplicate.

Comment: I wonder why my answer was downvoted, though. Anybody sees a problem with it?

Comment: @juanchopanza, makes sense. Done.